# In AngularJS, how can I apply a check function on all the responses of `$http`?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
$http({
    method: 'POST',
    url: '/getAllUsers'
}).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    if (data.length === 0) {
        $location.path('/admin/login');
    }
    // process data
    if (data.ok == 1) {
        // correct data
    } else {
        // error
    }
})
```

I use `$http` to fetch server data, and the server will respond an empty string if the auth fails. What I want to do is, if `data` is empty, then the application should redirect to login page. But since there are many controllers, and each controller has several `$http` call, so I don't want to copy and paste the directing code everywhere.

Is there any way I can "inject" this function on every `$http` response without writing the same code everywhere?

And am I able to apply it only on `$http` calls in some specific controllers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a `factory` definition and push it in `config phase` as `Interceptor` (using `$httpprovider`)

**Factory Definition**

```
angular.module('myApp').factory('httpInterceptor', ['$location', function($location) {
    var httpInterceptor = {
        response: function(config){ 
            if (config.data.trim() == "") {
                $location.path('\login');
            }

            return config;
        }
    };
    return httpInterceptor;
}]);
```

**Config Phase**

```
angular.module('myApp').config(['$httpProvider' ,function($httpProvider) {
   $httpProvider.interceptors.push('httpInterceptor');
}]);
```

Comment: But AngularJS said `ngRoute` module failed to load. I tried to log something in `response` function but nothing appeared.

Comment: Ah sorry, I inject a wrong module starting with `ng`. Problem solved.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a [http intercetor](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#interceptors). The intercetor's response method is called right after $http receives the response from the backend. You can modify the response or make other actions. The method get called with the http response object and needs to return the response object directly, or as a promise containing the response or a new response object.

```
$provide.factory('myHttpInterceptor', function() {
  return {
    'response': function(response) {
       if (/* response failed */ ) {
          // $rootScope broadcast
          // or $location login
          // or whatever you want
       }

       return response;
     }
   };
});

$httpProvider.interceptors.push('myHttpInterceptor');
```

**Edit**:
I'm not sure if this is correct usage of `$http` config (I'never done this..) but you could also conditionally add a `transformResponse` function to a single `$http` call [like this](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#usage):

```
function transformErrorResponse(data, headersGetter, status) {
  if (/* failed */)
    // handle failure
}

$http({ transformResponse : transformErrorResponse})
  .get(/*  */)
  .then(/*  */);
```

Comment: BTW, I actually want `$http` in some specific controllers to perform this check, while others don't. Can I know which controller the `$http` is in?

Comment: @Melkor You could try to set a transformResponse on the $http call (see edit).

Comment: It suddenly occurs to me that I can just check the controller in that factory because I actually assign controllers to different routes.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a simple config for $http in your module config and write your error handling in the transformResponse property of the $http config. 
Something like this:

```
angular.module("yourModule", []).config ($http) ->
     $http({

        transformResponse:(data, headersGetter, status)->
             /**Handle your data empty stuff here. ***/

      })
```

Comment: This is global, isn't it? Can I make exclude some `$http` call in some specific controllers?